# iterating over webelements in selenium always returns me only first row of the table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

here is my code, first I get all the rows of a table in all_trows variable, while iterating over it, I expect different output as each row has different text in it but I always get the values of the first tr of the table.

```
url = 'https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/eoi?field_commodity_group_eoi_rfi_tid=All&items_per_page=5'

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='block-system-main']/div/div[contains(@class,'view-content')] /table/tbody")))
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='block-system-main']/div/div[contains(@class,'view-footer')]/div[contains(@class,'page_result')]")))

page = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    current_page_flag = driver.find_element(By.XPATH , "//*[@id='block-system-main']/div/div[@class ='view-footer'] / div[@class ='page_result']").text.strip()
    WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='block-system-main']/div//tbody")))
    all_trows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='block-system-main']/div/div[@class = 'view-content'] / table / tbody / tr")

    for eachRow in all_trows:
        op_link = eachRow.find_element_by_xpath('//td[position() = 1]/a').get_attribute('href').strip()
        print(op_link)
        
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='block-system-main']/div/div[@class ='item-list']/ul/li")))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='block-system-main']/div/div[@class = 'item-list']/ul/li[contains(@class, 'pager-next')]/a").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='block-system-main']/div/div[@class ='view-footer'] / div[@class ='page_result']").text.strip()!= current_page_flag)
        page = page + 1
        print(page)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('no next button')
        # driver.quit()
        break
```

this is my output

```
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiunmiss17882
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiunmiss17882
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiunmiss17882
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiunmiss17882
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiunmiss17882
1
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiunficyp17877
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiunficyp17877
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiunficyp17877
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiunficyp17877
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiunficyp17877
2
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiescwa17908
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiescwa17908
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiescwa17908
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiescwa17908
https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/business-opportunities/EOI/eoiescwa17908
```

I expect while iterating over different rows I must get different href values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line

`op_link = eachRow.find_element_by_xpath('//td[position() = 1]/a').get_attribute('href').strip()`

When you iterating rows it always select the first item in DOM tree.

To select immediate child from DOM tree for each row you need to change with `.`

So your code should be

```
for eachRow in all_trows:
        op_link = eachRow.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[position() = 1]/a').get_attribute('href').strip()
        print(op_link)
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your response. It helped me alot. I am continuesly receiving a msg in my console while scrapping as [1123/152232.645:INFO:CONSOLE(2435)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'oldValue' of null", source: https://etendering.ted.europa.eu/cft/cft-display.html?cftId=7529 (2435)

Comment: could you tell me what does it mean how to handle it

Comment: I guess this is a separate issue and not attached with your original post.I appreciate if you post a new question and mention where you are getting problem and what you have expected.Thanks

Comment: it was just a warning which I could not understand that's why I put that here.

Comment: @TalibDaryabi : I didn't execute your code. However which line are you getting that warning?